# Is it possible to have text measures in SSAS tabular?

Tags: ssas, tabular

The question pretty much sums it up.

I am creating a model that involves textual status information on some processes. I would like to show these as text but cant for the life of me figure out how.

Tried FirstNonBlank(textualcolumn, 1) without luck. Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a text measure physically in any fact table I would suggest you to go for calculated measure. As per your post the measure has to represent some process status (I suppose Open or closed), you can easily write a MDX expression for the calculated measure.